# MonetDB - issue with dumping results of select statement into file

Tags: monetdb

I'm using "COPY SELECT ... INTO file" statement from within application code. After file is ready, next step is to move the file to different location. The only problem is that file created by MonetDB has only root permissions so my application code can't touch it. Is there a way to configure MonetDB so dumps are saved as specified user? or my only solution is to iterate results in batches in application and save to file that way. Dumps can range from several MB to 1GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run MonetDB as the same user that your application server is configured for. Also, both your application server and MonetDB probably should not run as 'root'.

There is no direct support to export files with different permissions. You could try configuring the umask for the user that the starts the DB.

Comment: Thank you, good call. For some reason when setting up dbfarm I executed it as a root. I changed permission to the same user as application and that solved the problem.